# Rewrite url for indicization

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I made a dynamic website but to be indexed on Google, I understand that I have to rewrite all URLs.

Every URL is in this form:

```
www.mysite.com/folder/?page=name
```

Where `name` is the name (with a lot of imagination) of pages.

I want that URLs in this form:

```
www.mysite.com/folder/name.php
```

To do so I need to use the `.htaccess` file but I can't understand what I should write in it. I read a lot of pages on internet but still I can't understand what should I do or what code I have to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this rule to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+folder/(?:index.php|)\?page=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /folder/%1.php? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/.]+)\.php$ /folder/?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks it works but now can't load the CSS. Is there a version that modify URLs and load the graphic? All contents are included on index.php, so the other pages haven't any tags or code. Just text, title, description and keywords.

Comment: Actually what this code really does, is a redirect the current page to another page. That's why every page is without graphic and layout. Loads the file `folder/name.php`. Infact I used this code replacing "folder" with "fmp" where there are all pages and URLs are converted to `fmp/page.php` but page.php is a file that really exist in that folder and browser thinks that I wanna see `fmp/page.php`as is it (without style, CSS or other code)

Comment: @Shika93 try removing the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` line

Comment: Nope. Doesn't rewrite